# Adobe LiveCycle PDF Submit Validation

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle

I have a LiveCycle PDF that has fields requiring validation.  I would like to be able to add a Button to perform a Submit that will ignore the validation on the form.  If I currently add a Button to the Form and setup the submit properties, validation occurs prior to the submit call which will cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xfa javascript api to disable validations. if you set xfa.host.validationsEnabled property false then xfa will not run validations. you can set this properties at presubmit event.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've gone around this is to make a SOAP call using a button. That would send the data and not validate.

On how to make a SOAP call, see an old post I had (see my answer): [SOAP Calls in LiveCycle Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623018/how-to-load-images-and-fragments-dynamically-in-livecycle-designer-forms)

Answer (score 0):

I just went through and removed validation where it was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form by javascript like this:

event.target.submitForm({cURL: encodeURI("http://..."), cSubmitAs:"PDF", cCharSet:"utf-8"});